# SoundManager 2 360Ui Installation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, soundmanager2

I'm trying to install SoundManager's [360Ui](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/360-player/) player.

But i cant seem to nail it.

This is the jQuery code in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/medium/includes/js/soundmanager2-nodebug.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/medium/includes/js/excanvas.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/medium/includes/js/berniecode-animator.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/medium/includes/js/360player.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
...

<script type="text/javascript">

    //some soundmanager settings
    soundManager.url = 'wp-content/themes/medium/swf/';
    soundManager.flashVersion = 9;
    soundManager.useHTML5Audio = true;
    soundManager.debugMode = false;

    </script>
```

And the HTML call:

```
<div class="ui360">
 <!-- dynamically-inserted block -->
 <div class="ui">
  <canvas class="sm2-canvas"></canvas>
  <span class="sm2-360btn"></span> 
  <div class="sm2-timing"></div>
  <div class="sm2-cover"></div>
 </div>
 <!-- /UI -->
 <a href="http://**.**.**.**:8000/live">
</div>
```

For some reason the small play button appears and a second later disappears.

- I'm looking to place the [big](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/360-player/canvas-visualization.html) player demo but i cant seem to
  properly initiate that player.
- All js files and css files from Demo folder are registered.

[My Website](http://www.tranceil.fm/new)

Its supposed to appear on the left panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you examine the firebug console you will see that a GET request to `http://tranceil.fm/new/readerPlayer.php` return a 301 redirect, that might be causing the issue

[image]

Comment: well..thats solves another problem i have :) but its not related as it appears.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a couple of years ago, but I was stuck on the same thing and here is how I solved it.

There is a second CSS file called **360player-visualization.css** that you need to include.

```
<link href="360-player/360player.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="360-player/360player-visualization.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then in the HTML, include `ui360-vis` class name as well.

```
<div class="ui360 ui360-vis">
    <a href="/link/to/audio.mp3"></a>
</div>
```

Just as you had it, you should also have a custom CSS to increase the size of the player:

```
.ui360,
.sm2-360ui {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
}
```

And as you had it, the three required JS files:

```
<script src="360-player/script/berniecode-animator.js"></script>
<script src="soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js"></script>
<script src="360-player/script/360player.js"></script>
```